# How to use regex to replace a particular field in a formatted file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with following formatted file I need to parse

```
field_1 {
    field_2 {
        ....
    }
    field_i_want_to_replace {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
....
```

I need a pre-processor in python to parse those files and delete the content of some particular fields. In the above example, the processed file will look like:

```
field_1 {
    field_2 {
        ....
    }
    field_i_want_to_replace {}
    ....
}
....
```

So the preprocessor needs to locate the particular field "field_i_want_to_replace" and then delete the contents between the brackets. I'm trying to do the following but the regex can't parse the file correctly.

```
regex = r'(field_i_want_to_replace )\{.*?\}'
print re.sub(regex,'field_i_want_to_replace {}', file_in_string)
```

Is there sth wrong with the regex I'm using?

Comment: the `file_in_string` is a `string`, right? cause for me it worked on **python 2.7** using your way...

Comment: Yes, it's in string format. However, it doesn't work for me. I still print the original string in my console

Comment: I forgot to mention that I replaced the `...` with actual strings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.` character is not matching any newlines, so it will not continue after the left curly bracket.

To change this behavior, just add the [`re.DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) (or `re.S`) as a keyword arg to your `re.sub`:

```
>>> regex = r'(field_i_want_to_replace )\{.*?\}'
>>> print re.sub(regex,'field_i_want_to_replace {}', file_in_string, flags=re.DOTALL)
field_1 {
    field_2 {
        ....
    }
    field_i_want_to_replace {}
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that there could be nested curly in "field_i_want_to_replace". for example, field_i_want_to_replace { field_n{} }

Comment: In that case I don't think regex is the best tool at your disposal...see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns), unless you have more information. For instance, do you know what the next field is called?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I dont have any information on the nested fields.

Comment: Python's `re` doesn't support recursive calls but if you are able to import `regex` module into your project then there is a solution. @user2744486

Comment: @user2744486 Although you can use a different regex flavor, as I mentioned that's really not the right tool for this.